# Is there a way to make a View "untappable" allowing taps to connect with the View behind it?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've got a view in .overlay and I'd like it to ignore taps because it's somehow blocking my content behind it from registering any, is there a solution that would allow me to simply add a property like .ignore so that taps can pass through to the View behind it containing an .onTapGesture?

I've also got this problem elsewhere in my app where a view is .clipped yet still, the portion that is out of bounds and clipped (not visible) seems to be blocking taps to the View behind it. This may be a bug, I'm not sure though

Comment: You can try with "contentShape" modifier.

Comment: @MarcT. I was able to use contentShape modifiers to solve my problem so if you post that comment as an answer I'll mark it as solved, thanks for letting me know about their existence!

Comment: I posted it as an answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `contentShape` modifier you can define the content shape for hit testing. If this shape will have a width and height of 0 you can not tap it.

```
struct HitTestingView: View {

    struct HitTestingShape : Shape {
        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            return Path(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        }
    }

    var body: some View {

        Text("Hello World!")
            .padding(20)
            .background(Color.blue.cornerRadius(8))
            .contentShape(HitTestingShape())
            .onTapGesture {
                print("Tap")
        }
    }
}
```